# Is vote-buying a thing?

Tags: discussion

Increasingly, I've seen very half-baked, mostly offtopic questions getting "large" amounts of upvotes fairly quickly (within minutes of posting). [Example that prompted this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44988890/3000206) (it's since been deleted for some reason, so you'll need enough rep to view it).

This question doesn't really show any research effort, and doesn't appear to be ontopic (maybe thinly), yet at the time of posting, it has 3 votes!

This is far from the first time I've seen this, and as I said, it seems to be getting worse. It's not uncommon for me to browse over new questions in the SO feed, and see similar questions with 1 or 2 votes soon after posting.

The cynic in me fears that someone may have found a way to sell votes to people who want more attention, but don't want to work for it.

Are people buying attention? Are people becoming far more lenient about what's considered upvote worthy? Is there an effort to be overly generous to new users?

Comment: Voting fraud, of various flavours, is ......not unknown:)

Comment: "This question doesn't really show any research effort, and doesn't appear to be ontopic (maybe thinly), yet at the time of posting, it has 3 votes! " - and no downvote or closevote from you (when I checked it 12 minutes after your post here)

Comment: @Tom No, I got distracted. I had only a few minutes before I had to leave for work, and wanted to type this question on in my laptop instead of my phone. By the time I checked back, it was deleted. I was going to vote after, but I didn't think it was pressing.

Comment: Question and account are gone. This was a clear-cut question of voting fraud with sockpuppet accounts.

Comment: ^^ what a surprise:(

Comment: @MartijnPieters while we're at it, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44987078) looks like a beginning of a beautiful voting ring. It surprised me few hours ago how two bland link-only answers could get +4 each but back then I thought it's usual anrdoid tag idiocy. After reading your comment here I decided to click through participants accounts and their posts and their rep history and what I saw felt quite suspicious (eg oldest account has recent vote correction etc)

Comment: @gnat - Thanks for the head-up. This has been handled. What a mess.

Comment: To your core question: no, I haven't seen anyone actually selling votes in my entire time here. The people who are defrauding the voting system are the kind who come here to try to have people do their work for free. They're not going to pay for anything. It wouldn't be a great investment, because they'd lose it all as soon as we found out and had SE invalidate the votes.

Answer (score -28):

It seems some people intentionally down vote beginners even though answers are to the correct context, whereas beginners giving non-contextual answers get many up-votes for some unknown reason. I feel moderators should check if up-votes or down-votes given to answers are for real.

Comment: 'I feel moderators should check if up-votes or down-votes given to answers are for real' - what do you mean be 'real' and how many mods do you expect would be required to check votes for 'reality', (to the nearest 1000)?  Are you volunteering to pay them?

Comment: I can assure you that my down-votes are for real. Do know that moderators have limited possibilities to verify if votes are legit and when they suspect something is off the have to defer to SE-staff.

Comment: How are we to know whether someone is a "beginner" or not? Answers that are incorrect or unhelpful get downvoted. It just so happens that beginners are more likely to write incorrect or unhelpful answers. There is no conspiracy afoot.

Comment: Regardless of how blatantly incorrect this answer is (as explained by the other commenters), how exactly is this even remotely related to the topic at hand?